# How to reconnect SignalR if its closed using react .Net core ( SQL dependency)?

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, signalr

We developed database change notification using SignalR react .Net core. It is working fine but once connection has closed then how to restart connection again using react .Net core?

Comment: You can only reconnect from the client. Whether SQL or not isn't really relevant.

Comment: The Javascript client [can already reconnect automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reconnect-clients). Post your Javascript code please.

Comment: *Which* SignalR are you using? The old ASP.NET SignalR, or the new, completely rewritten ASP.NET Core SignalR? Which SignalR client did you add to your react project? The up-to-date package is `@microsoft/signalr`

Answer (score 6):

The question doesn't clarify whether the old SignalR or ASP.NET Core SignalR is used. ASP.NET Core SignalR was completely rewritten.

The current Javascript client, [@microsoft/signalr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr) supports [automatic reconnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#automatically-reconnect). All you need to do is add `.withAutomaticReconnect()` when creating the hub connection:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/chatHub")
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();
```

**Update**

The [article explaining how @microsoft/signalr works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is *very* thorough. The [Reconnect clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reconnect-clients) section explains:

- how to enable automatic reconnection with a simple `.withAutomaticReconnect()`
- how to customize the number of retries and delays between them by passing an array of delay times to `withAutomaticReconnect`, eg: `.withAutomaticReconnect([0, 0, 10000])`. The default is `[0, 2000, 10000, 30000]` for a total of 42 seconds.
- instead of an array of delays, a callback can be used :

```
.withAutomaticReconnect({
        nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: retryContext => {
            if (retryContext.elapsedMilliseconds < 60000) {
                // If we've been reconnecting for less than 60 seconds so far,
                // wait between 0 and 10 seconds before the next reconnect attempt.
                return Math.random() * 10000;
            } else {
                // If we've been reconnecting for more than 60 seconds so far, stop reconnecting.
                return null;
            }
        }
    })
```

- how to handle the `onreconnecting` and `onreconnected` events and possibly log, or display a UI notification :

```
connection.onreconnecting((error) => {
    console.assert(connection.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Reconnecting);

    document.getElementById("messageInput").disabled = true;

    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = `Connection lost due to error "${error}". Reconnecting.`;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});
```

- What to do when reconnection ultimately fails. In this case the `onclose` is fired and can be used to reconnect :

```
connection.onclose(async () => {
    await start();
});
```

Comment: Its Asp.net core SignalR with react.

Comment: Thank u for quick reply .                                                        
  **WithAutomaticReconnect()**   it's available for react signalr ? It's not working with react signalr .

Comment: @AbhishekMarathe what `react signalr` do you refer to? There are some packages that forked the *old* client and were eventually abandoned, when the new one came out. You don't *need* a react-specific client anyway - the client is just Javascript. You can easily create your own class/component and raise events or call callbacks on a hub event.

Comment: i am using **@microsoft/signalr** package and written below code inside function.     Demo(                                                                                                this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/Demo").withAutomaticReconnect().build(); )  On onclose event calling same function but its not working.                                 this.connection.onclose(() => {

                   this.Demo();
                
                    console.log("Close");
                
                }
            });

Comment: The link to the docs show that the event raised on reconnection is `onreconnecting` and `onreconnected`, not `onclose`. `onclose` will fire only if reconnection fails after 4 attempts

Comment: Thank u very much for help @Panagiotis Kanavos , I have checked docs .Now my question is if connection  closed after 4 attempts then how we will start connection again using react @microsoft/signalr .

Comment: @AbhishekMarathe at that point you should warn the user. If 4 retries failed, a 5th one will likely *also* fail. The docs explain [how to reconnect manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#manually-reconnect) - listen to `onclose` and call the `connection.start` inside it. The same page shows how to change the number of retries, how to change the delay between retries, or how to use a function to determine when to retry